# How do I create a Unix timestamp on Android?

Tags: android, unix-timestamp

How do I create a Unix timestamp on Android?

I want to create a URL post request with a Unix timestamp on the end of the url.

Comment: You should really try to describe your problems better.  Don't leave people to guess what it is that you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: Is this similar to an epoch, essentially a running value?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

```
 long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```

Comment: `L` is redundant

Comment: As simple as it can be ☺

Answer (score 15):

It's quite simple:

```
long timestamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTime() / 1000;
```

Comment: Is this as good as `System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L` ? (It looks less efficient to me - unless I am missing something?)

Comment: For getting the current time, @Nesim has the better answer, but this answer is great if you already have a calendar object with a custom time. `myCalendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000`

Answer (score -2):

Updated answer with Kotlin:

```kotlin
val unix = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. It should be `Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis / 1000`. Check the other answers.